# How much DATA section memory is loaded along with Code section in C

Tags: c++, c, linux, static

I have created a shared library where I have static const data section and code section of 4 functions.

Here are the details of my static const data section,

```
static const u32 T0[256] = { 256 NON_ZERO value };
static const u32 T1[256] = {256  NON_ZERO value };
static const u32 T2[256] = {256  NON_ZERO value };
static const u32 T3[256] = {256  NON_ZERO value };
static const u32 T4[256] = {256  NON_ZERO value };
static const u32 T5[256] = {256  NON_ZERO value };
static const u32 T6[256] = {256  NON_ZERO value };
static const u32 T7[256] = {256  NON_ZERO value };
static const u32 T8[256] = {256  NON_ZERO value };
static const u32 T9[10] = {10 NON_ZERO value };
```

Different functions defined just below the static const section

```
int A();
int B();

// Access different index of T0 - T3 table 
void C();

void D();
```

As per my understanding the text/code section will contain the executable
instruction whereas data section will contain initialized static data ( for simplicity in my case all are static const)

Inside C() function , different index of T0,T1,T2 and T3 are accessed in random order.

Intentionally, inside C(), I have not accessed T0[0].

**However,
every time I call C() function, it is loading T0[0] irrespective of whether T0[0] is accessed or not inside C() function.**

**My question is how much adjacent memory of data section is loaded along with code section?**

I was thinking may be whole 4KB page loaded, so everytime C() function called, whole 4KB page loaded , therefore
T0[0] is also loaded along with it.

but, the experimental result shows THIS CONCEPT IS NOT TRUE/CORRECT.

Let me explain it elaborately as below.

I have calculated the distance between function C() and different static const data as below

```
Base address of C - Base address of T0[0] = 3221 Bytes
Base address of C - Base address of T1[0] = 4345 Bytes
Base address of C - Base address of T2[0] = 5369 Bytes
Base address of C - Base address of T3[0] = 6393 Bytes
```

So, whenever C() is invoked , ONLY 64Bytes (i.e. T0[0] ) is loaded . T0[1], T0[2],... the part of T0 array which also 
belong to same 4KB page with C() NOT LOADED(if whole 4KB page is loaded then these must be loaded, but experiment result shows they weren't loaded). Hence my concept whole 4KB page memory is loaded is wrong.

**EDIT 1:** based on comments of @nemetroid, C() and T0[0] may belong to different page. That's why I am adding the base address of both C() and T0[0] here.

```
Base address of T0[0]=0xB7758D40 ,
Base address of C=0xB7758047 when T0[0] is loaded.
```

In other experiment, when I add another static const of 64Byte ( like static const int DATA=10; ) before
static const u32 T0[256] = {.....}

these distances become

```
Base address of C - Base address of T0[0] =3385 Bytes [ =64 + Base address of C - Base address of T0[0]]
Base address of C - Base address of T1[0] = 4345+64 Bytes =4409 Bytes [=64 + Base address of C - Base address of T0[0]+1024]
Base address of C - Base address of T2[0] = 5369+64 Bytes = 5433 Bytes[=64 + Base address of C - Base address of T0[0]+2*1024]
Base address of C - Base address of T3[0] = 6393 +64 Bytes = 6457 Bytes[=64 + Base address of C - Base address of T0[0]+3*1024]
```

EDIT1 :

```
Base address of T0[0]=0xB775cD80 (just shifted by 64Bytes),
Base address of C=0xB775C047 ( in this case T0[0] is not loaded)
```

**Now, although T0[0] still present in same 4KB page with C()(ONLY shifted by 64bytes), it is not loaded whenever C() is invoked.** So here again I can't say along with C(), whole 4KB page was loaded.

**Can you help me to explain/understand WHY T0[0] is always accessed/loaded whenever C() is invoked although it is not accessed/used 
inside C() ?**

or any link to understand the memory layout of program and size of memory loaded during execution of program.

I am using Debian OS and gcc compiler.

**Note :** To calculate whether T0[0] is loaded or not , before invoking C(), I just flushed T0[0] using clflush() instruction and then after
C() is invoked I have calculated access time using rdtsc().

EDIT 1:
I am using Intel Core i3 machine.

```
Size of L1=32KB, 8 way associative, cache line size=64bytes
Size of L2=256KB, 8 way associative, cache line size=64bytes
Size of L3=3MB, 12 way associative, cache line size=64bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Pages are aligned to the page size. So, if you have a page size of 4 kB, `0xAABBC000 - 0xAABBCFFF` belong to the same page, as do `0xAABBD000 - 0xAABBDFFF`, etc.

So if `C` has address `0xAABBCF00` and `T0` has address `0xAABBD000` the difference between their addresses is less than 4 kB, but they still belong to different pages. However, `T0[0]` and `T0[1]` in extreme likelihood belong to the same page. Try running `objdump -h a.out`.

Comment: If you reread the post after seeing the basic info at the end of the post, it should be clear 4Kb paging is irrelevant and the topic is cache lines.  Of course those are also strictly aligned, so your point about distance vs. alignment is still important, just on a size smaller than 4Kb and using the end of c() not its beginning.

Comment: @nemetroid ,@JSF thanks for comment. I have printed the base address in both cases. Base address of T0=0xB7758D40 , base address of C=0xB7758047 when T0[0] is loaded. After adding static const DATA=10 , Base address of T0=0xB775cD80 (just shifted by 64Bytes), base address of C=0xB775C047 ( in this case T0[0] is not loaded) . However in both cases both T0[0] and C() belong to the same page boundary.

Answer (score 0):

The whole cache line is loaded when any part of it is loaded.  You seem to be describing a situation in which the beginning of the data is in the same cache line as part of the code.  I'm surprised it would be linked/loaded that way, but it should be easy to confirm (or contradict) with a debugger.
The cache line size and other details of this behavior will vary by CPU model.

Looking at the base address of C() was easier but less informative.  What matters is the address of the highest instruction of C() fetched (not necessarily executed).  I expect that is in the same cache line as the start of data.

Comment: in above case beginning of data is not in the same cache line as part of code as the distance is 3221bytes whereas the cache line size is 64bytes. It may be possible they mapped to same cache line, but in that situation while C() is invoked T0[0] will not loaded as it is not present in next consecutive address belongs to same cache line.

Comment: can you tell me how to find the highest instructions of C() fetched(not necessarily executed)? by generating assembly code ? I am wondering in that case also how will it be helpful to find out the reason of loading T0[0] along with C() which is far distance away (may be they mapped to same cache line, but definitely not in the same cache line). I hope by same cache you want to say within 64bytes of cache line both code of C() and data of T0[0] is present side by side continuously, so whenever C() is invoked T0[0] is also loaded as it is present in same cache line.

Comment: In my case, distance between C() and T0[0] is 3221bytes, so there is no way or any possibility that they belong to same cache line. BTW, I have printed the base address in both cases. Base address of T0=0xB7758D40 , base address of C=0xB7758047 when T0[0] is loaded. After adding static const DATA=10 , Base address of T0=0xB775cD80 (just shifted by 64Bytes), base address of C=0xB775C047 ( in this case T0[0] is not loaded) . Surprisingly, in both cases, they belong to different cache lines.

Comment: You measured the distance from the entry point of C() to T0[0] as 3221.  But C() is many bytes of code.  You haven't told us how many.  But the symptoms you describe make it very likely C() is nearly 3221 bytes of code.  Finding the last byte of C() is only easy if you look at and understand the assembly code.  Last fetched byte can be much much harder to deduce, but won't be much different from last byte.  What CPU? (How do you know the cache line size is 64 bytes).  You showed T0[0] on a 64 byte boundary, so this could be prefetch oddity, or cache size over 64 or my theory is wrong.

Comment: I am using  Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz .  cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/coherency_line_size 
gives cache line size (64bytes) . Also cat /proc/cpuinfo gives clflush size : 64 cache_alignment : 64.

Comment: The distance between D() and T0[0] is 1743bytes whereas distance between C() and T0[0] is 3221bytes. This means in between T0[0] and C(), there is D() . So I think your explanation with respect to last byte or last address also not correctly pointing WHY T0[0] is prefetching or loading ?